# How to store and fetch value from session in java class adf 12c

Tags: jsf

I am writing a java class in oracle fusion middleware web app adf 12c.
I want to know how to store value in session and cookie inside java class function and fetch value from session on .jsf page.
for example here is java class function.

```
public String it_name() {

  //want to store this itName in session and cookie    
  String itName = "OracleIT";    
  return itName;

}
```

Remember want to fetch value from session on .jsf page adf faces components also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store a variable in Session you can use the following JSFUtils function :

```
/**
* Convenience method for setting Session variables.
* @param key object key
* @param object value to store
*/

public static void storeOnSession(String key, Object object) {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getFacesContext();
    Map sessionState = ctx.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    sessionState.put(key, object);
}
```

In your case :

```
// Java file
public String it_name() {
    String itName = "OracleIT";   
    storeOnSession("itName",itName)
    return itName;
}

//JSF : 
<af:outputText value="${sessionScope.itName}" id="pt_ot1" />
```

Comment: also please let me know how i can retrieve value from session in another bean class? , how to destroy session and cookie? and how to store and fetch value from cookie?

Comment: the documentation didn't solve my problem, can you please write down the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) 
        context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("itName ", "oracleIT");
        Map aDFContext = ADFContext.getCurrent().getSessionScope();
    System.err.println("itName:"+aDFContext.get("itName").toString());
```

use can use EL like this

```
 #{sessionScope.itName}
```

use can use groovy expression like this

```
adf.context.sessionScope.itName
```

Comment: also please let me know how can i store value in cookie? and how to destroy session and cookie value